# Facebook deep linking target_url parameter missing iOS

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, ios7.1, deep-linking

I am posting links and photos using `me/photos` and `me/feed` of the GraphAPI on Facebook from my iOS App. I specify the `link` parameter when posting to Facebook. This should return a `target_url` field when parsing the url parameter in the`- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation` callback when tapping the AppName in the native Facebook App post.

However, I only get `fbXXXXXXXXXX://authorize/#access_token=XXXXXXX&expires_in=3600`. Why is there no `target_url` field?
The following link explains that it should be returned if the `link` parameter is specified when creating the post on Facebook.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/app-links

I know this has been replaced by AppLinks but I am using an older SDK of Facebook(3.2) which should cater for this.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like a bug with Facebook. A bug report was submitted to Facebook with the same symptoms:

https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/651932701585804/

It has since been fixed and is awaiting release.