# Facebook iOS deep linking - can't parse request_ids since target_url is missing

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, deep-linking

First I just want to state that I already know [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24615719/facebook-deep-linking-target-url-parameter-missing-ios) exist. It is somewhat similar to mine. But since I don't have enough reputation I couldn't comment and ask if there was any progress on the issue.

Ok, so I'm trying to retrive the request_ids from the target_url, as per the [Facebook docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/mobile/ios-tutorial#requests_step4). When the user taps on a request in the native Facebook iOS app, iOS switches to my app, and when I try to process the app launch url in order to parse out the request_ids, I can't even find the target_url.

The launch url should look something like:

```
fb00000000000000://authorize/#access_token=00000000000000&expires_in=86400&target_url= http://m.facebook.com/apps/friendsmashsample?fb_source=notification&request_ids=abc&ref=notif&app_request_type=Duser_to_user
```

But in my case the `target_url`  is missing, and instead it looks like:

```
fb00000000000000://authorize/#access_token=0000000000000&expires_in=86400
```

So my question is: How do I get the `target_url`, so that I can parse the `request_ids` in order to deep link in my app?

Thanks!

Comment: Is that your original fbApp Id? If it is remove it asap.

Comment: I'm having this issue too.  Funny thing is that the last time I tested this with the same code, it worked - something's changed.

Comment: I think this is a bug, because this used to work for me.  I filed a bug with Facebook, let's see what happens - https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/651932701585804/